# Change gear cables for Shimano Tiagra 4603

Tags: gears, racing-bikes

Can't seem to figure out the way to enter the cable shifter which broke while riding!!!

Can't also find a manual or video out there helping me to replace it.

Comment: Did the inner cable break inside your shifter ?    IE, is there a little piece of wire lost inside the shifter's body ? This can be easy or very hard to resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

manual is here

https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/dm/ST0001/DM-ST0001-05-ENG.pdf

exploded diagram here

https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/ST-4603/EV-ST-4603-3155.pdf

all via si.shimano.com

Video for similar shifter

Answer (score 3):

For the RD, shift to the smallest sprocket i.e. activate the inner lever for as long as it clicks. Pull the brake lever, hint: open the caliper in the way you would to remove the wheel. That way you can push the gear cable out of the brifter.